# git clone -b tag results in - warning: Remote branch not found in upstream origin, using HEAD instead

Tags: git

If you try to clone a git repo and checkout a tag in a single command by using the `-b` or `--branch` flag for clone:

```
git clone -b v0.8.2 https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module.git
```

You may run into an error such as:

```
warning: Remote branch v0.8.2 not found in upstream origin, using HEAD instead
```

Answer (score 6):

Checking out a tag via a `git clone` call is not supported by git before version 1.7.10. Instead it is necessary to execute:

```
git clone https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module.git
cd lua-nginx-module
git checkout v0.8.2
cd ..
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your `which git` executable. Try `whereis git` as well and pick one.

If your `git --version` is older than 1.7.10 then you'll see this issue. If you want to fail (for a wrong / invalid branch) and succeed for a valid branch, then use `git` which is higher version.

For example, if I had `git` (default) in **/usr/bin/git** (and if it is **1.7.1**) _ I'll get the same error like you got for an invalid branch.

If I use `/opt/tools/bin/git` (let's say it's `git version 2.14.1`), then that git clone command will exit with an error code **128** as expected (for any invalid/non-existent branch) and exit code as **0** (for a valid branch).